# Makemkv for Freebsd

Tags: c++, c, freebsd, ports

a few weeks ago I decided to start porting the linux version of makemkv to Freebsd 10 starting from an existng repo I found on GitHub (from a contributor called osokin). From what the repo's owner stated it should be apparently possible to build a very old version of the application under Freebsd 9. Unfortunately the zip file mentioned in his make file is nowhere to be found on the internet, and moreover the version he is referring to is so very old that I am afraid most of the new Blu Ray DVD won't even be correctly decrypted.

From this point I started my quest and tried to get the command line utility of makemkv to compile, but I am stuck to a point where I cannot make any progress. I would like to say that I am not at all a C/C++ developer and the only reason why I am trying to do this is purely "passion".

In order to give you a better understanding of what I did I created a git repo of the port which is available here https://github.com/HiMyNameIsIlNano/makemkv. The structure of the package is quite simple. Inside the "files" folder are all the patches that are applied before the port gets compiled using the Makefile available in the main folder. The folder "works" contains the files part of the makemkv which are fetched from the internet and compiled. Here are the errors I get when compiling [error logs](http://pastebin.com/eykfPLz4).

One relevant change I made for this freebsd version of makemkv is that I am using the ports tree in order to satisfy the dependencies that this port needs, as the makemkv and libeml are already part of the port tree and I do not see any reason why I should be using another version of the same libraries to build this port. On the other hand, I think that some of the errors I get are related to a wrong usage of this dependency, but I tried a lot of different things before giving up and asking for help to experts like you.

Could you please help me understand what is wrong with the port and how it is possible to fix the error and move on?

Best regards,
Daniele.

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please see [ask]. State the specific problem and provide a [mcve]. Don't be too chatty; the history is of no interest. Also note that you are required to provide all **in the question itself**. No links, no images (unless really required).

Comment: IF I were you, I'd post this on https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Will. Thanks to all the other users for the links to the how-to(s). I will try to be more concise next time.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you haven't run the `configure` script. The `ffabicfg.h` should have been created by `configure`. See [this output](http://www.makemkv.com/forum2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8802) (search for `config.status: creating libffabi/src/ffabicfg.h`):

```
~/Desktop/makemkv-oss-1.9.1 > ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
(...)
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating libffabi/src/ffabicfg.h
config.status: libffabi/src/ffabicfg.h is unchanged
```

The `configure` script would also create the `Makefile`. See the Wikipedia article for more information how the [`configure` script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script) works.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I am currently checking how to get the configure script to work on BSD.